# Qt C++ Виджет в центре родительского окна

Tags: c++, qt, виджет

> Создается  класс наследуемый от `QDialog` в одном из методов его
>   реализации создается кнопка `QPushButton * push= new
>   QPushButton(this);` хочу сделать так что бы она была в центре
>   родительского виджета. По умолчанию кнопка создается в верхнем левом
>   углу и имеет x и y которые равны нулю.

Как сделать кнопке `setGeometry` так чтобы кнопка была в центре родительского виджета? а то ручками задавать не правильно.

Comment: Из половины ширины(высоты) родителя вычесть половину ширины(высоты) дочернего? Ну и реагировать на ресайз, конечно.

Comment: Чтобы было совсем правильно, можно сделать кастомный менеджер компоновки - унаследоваться от QLayout ([пример](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-layouts-flowlayout-example.html))

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего сделать так

[image: Изображение]

Добиться этого можно таким образом:

```
 Window(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QWidget(parent)
    {
        QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
        hLayout->addStretch();
        hLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton);
        hLayout->addStretch();

        QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
        vLayout->addStretch();
        vLayout->addLayout(hLayout);
        vLayout->addStretch();

        setLayout(vLayout);
    }
```

Можно провернуть то же самое при помощи `QGridLayout`, но у него нет метода `addStretch`, поэтому придется писать что-то вроде

```
gLayout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);, 1, 0, 1, 1);
```

Comment: А если в этом окне есть уже виджет. Нужно поверх этого виджета который уже есть в окне вывести кнопку.

Comment: Виджет поверх другого виджета стандартные компоновщики размещать не будут. Но я, если честно, не представляю зачем это нужно.

Comment: У нас есть форма, в ней таблица на почти весь виджет, если таблица долго заполняется, окно подвисает. Перед тем как окно подвиснет, хочу выводить окошко с сообщением типо messageBox с сообщением идет загрузка данных, а как виджет развиснет, т.е загрузятся все данные он исчезает. Для этого я создаю кнопку с текстом внутри, если у нас виджет загружается больше секунды, то я на 1 мсек захожу в условие с выводом кнопки через QApplication::processEvent(), а как виджет загрузится кнопка явно удаляется.

Comment: А почему кнопка не может быть в диалоговом окошке?

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так.

```
QRect geometry = this->geometry();
int x = geometry.width() - width() / 1.5;
```

так как он берет начало от начала другой формы а она длинная, мне нужна ее середина.

`int y = screenGeometry.height() - height / 2;`

Далее в кнопку устаналиваю

`push->setGeometry(x,y,282,50);`